# Alert says the vote limit has been reached, and to try after 16 hours

Tags: support, voting

I am shown a alert that says, "You have reached vote limit try again after 16 hours."

What is the secret behind this?

Comment: You can cast only 40 votes in a day. Looks like you have exhausted all of them, ergo the pop up.

Comment: no i have cast 39 votes yet!

Comment: It's by design...see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90202/please-dont-require-answer-votes-to-be-cast-before-question-votes/90256#90256 for a network-wide explanation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 30 votes per day, plus 10 question votes; those 10 question votes must be cast before 30 answer votes.

If you vote only for answers, you get 30 votes per day; if you vote only questions, you get 40 votes per day.
If you vote answers, and questions, your limit depends on which order you voted; for example, your limit is 39 if you vote using the following order:

- 15 answers
- 9 questions
- 15 answers

Keep in mind that:

- The Stack Exchange day is based on UTC time.
- When you get the message "you have still X votes" that is the number of votes you have. You can vote answers, or questions, but that is the number of votes you can still cast.